# Add automatically the resources files in the AssemblyInfo manifest

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-assembly

After add manually a very long list of resources in the assembly file, i ask someone if is not possible to make this action programmatically. It don't understand why after define as embeded resources these files aren't added automatically using vs2010. I hate to make manually!

```
[assembly: WebResource("Project.XXX.YYY.ZZZ.BannerCarousel.ascx", "text/html")]
```

... more 100 lines...

Can someone suggest a better way ?  Thanks.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15494/Load-WebForms-and-UserControls-from-Embedded-Resou

Comment: thanks, I searching a way to read the resources folder and automatically register the webresources, scripts and controls files in the assembly infofile.

Comment: Well, did you succeed?